# How to simulate trackpad zoom on MacOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

Right now I'm building an iPhone app that can replace Trackpad on Macbook, I managed to do certain gestures, but I couln't figure it out how to make the zoom function. When I tried to Pinch on the iPhone screen I got the pinch scale value but I don't know what I'm going to do with the value when I send it to Macbook, so is there anyway to simulate scaling like trackpad does using Swift?

Comment: There are open source trackpad simulators, how do they simluate the zoom gesture? Have you used an event monitor/tap to see what the events from a real trackpad are?

Comment: I haven't used event monitor, how?

Comment: I'm sorry, the documentation of `addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)` says that it can't monitor gesture events.